# Transformer current draw

Tags: transformer

If a transformer draws more current than the voltage source can supply, what happens to the voltage across the primary? It should be the same as the source but it has been reduced from load current canceling original flux and the source is unable to supply more current.

eg. http://inverter-circuit.com/12vdc-to-220vac-inverter-with-555-timer.html#jp-carousel-127

Comment: Quite simply it drops.

Comment: How does that fit with kirchoffs law. The sum of all voltage drops wouldn't equal zero.

Comment: You should draw this, it's not clear from your question what you actually mean. If it draws more than the source can supply, the source will drop - this is not strange nor breaks any laws, so it's unclear what you mean.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of this circuit where the current is limited by the transistors.  http://inverter-circuit.com/12vdc-to-220vac-inverter-with-555-timer.html#jp-carousel-127

Comment: Please add an example schematic. It's highly unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @winny See my previous comment.

Comment: Please insert it into your question using the edit button.

Answer (score 1):

If any load, in your case a transformer, tries to draw more current than the source can supply, then the source voltage and so the load voltage will drop.

What happens after that depends on the design of the source. It might be designed to shut down safely, or to drive a constant current at a level it can supply, or it might just let the smoke out.